# devtools::check() produces warning: invalid input found on input connection

Tags: r, devtools

When I run `devtools::check()`, I get the following warning:

> checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... WARNING
>
> Warning in parse(file = files, n = -1L) :
>
> invalid input found on input connection 'bbsBayes-Ex.R'

I'm not even sure where to begin fixing this warning, considering it does not tell me which .R file is causing this issue. Has anyone run into this warning before that can shed some light on where to begin?

EDIT 1: This warning does not happen on Travis CI.

EDIT 2: This initial warning came from R Version 3.4.1 on Windows 10. I just updated to R Version 3.5.1 and no longer get this warning.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in an example in `bbsBayes`. Checking the package will, by default, also check the examples, which is an easy place to run into namespacing problems, etc

Comment: Do you have the package in a GitHub repo you can link to or something?

Comment: @duckmayr This is the package: https://github.com/BrandonEdwards/bbsBayes   The error message is particularly not informative since "bbsBayes-Ex.R" is clearly just the name of the package.

Comment: Sorry, a couple more questions: What operating system are you building on? Which version of R are you using? These questions might be informative since the warning doesn't pop up on Travis-CI.

Comment: @duckmayr R version 3.4.1, Windows 10.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce on my laptop, which runs Ubuntu, so I'll check it on a Windows computer tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry it took a bit, but I was finally able to try checking this on a Windows system. On Windows 8.1 running R 3.5.1 this warning did not pop up. I'll try to get R 3.4.1 running a little later to see what happens.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this warning once I used R 3.4.1 on Windows 8.1. I am investigating now.

Comment: Hey @duckmayr sorry I haven't been responsive, I appreciate your help looking into this! I just made an edit to the post, but I updated my R to version 3.5.1 and no longer get this warning. Perhaps some odd, version-specific warning?